# The following method did not exist: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V

Tags: spring, scala, apache-spark

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    spark-core_2.12
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    spark-streaming_2.12
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    spark-streaming-kafka_2.11
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    scala-library
    <version>2.11.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using above version. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using versions of libraries for different Scala: 2.12 and 2.11.

Please use <strike>either</strike>

```
spark-core_2.12
spark-streaming_2.12
spark-streaming-kafka_2.12
scala-library  2.12.x
```

(`spark-streaming-kafka_2.12` does not exist) or

```
spark-core_2.11
spark-streaming_2.11
spark-streaming-kafka_2.11
scala-library  2.11.x
```

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293697/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-product-initlsc)

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906763/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-product-initlscala-productv)

Comment: I guess spark-streaming-kafka_2.12 does not exist. I used 11 vesrion but getting different error.

Comment: .factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaPairInputDStream' defined in class path resource [com/dreampay/reconsonsumer/config/Configuration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream]: Factory method 'javaPairInputDStream' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error getting partition metadata for 'demo'. Does the topic exist?

Comment: I can see demo topic is alrady exist in my local kafka

Comment: @Ravi You should create a new question with deatails about your bean config and what you're doing in Spark and Kafka.

Comment: @Ravi Great. What was the issue? (If you're satisfied with the answer you can accept it.)

Comment: I commented this line kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest") in my code and it worked.

Comment: i am creating one pipeline using spring boot,kafka and spark for big file processing(like computation ,validation etc)